# Problem with this weird series

Tags: sequences-and-series

So, I came across a problem in 'Complex Variables by Schaum'

> Given, $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}...$converges to S

> Prove that the rearranged series:
> $$1+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{7}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}-\frac{1}{6}+...=\frac{3}{2}S$$
> (Hint: Take half of first series and write it as $0+\frac{1}{2}+0-\frac{1}{4}$ and add term by term to the first series.

Now the hint pretty much does it. When you take half of S and add term by term to S you do get the asked series and its proved.

My issue:

The asked series can itself be re-written as:

$$1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{6}....=S$$

The asked series is basically the same series as the first one and yet their summations are different. How could that be possible??

What is the noob mistake I am doing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: The example illustrates the fact that you need aditional hypothesis on your series to guarantee that the sum remains the same if you rearrange the terms

Comment: Wow. So just having the same series is not enough to give the same sum??

Comment: Is this something taught mainstream mathematics in the sense that there is an intuitive explanation to this? Cause I have come across this the first time and its freaking me out.

Comment: I learned this when I first  learned about conditional convergence. There's a proof in the second link in my answer. It's not hard.

Comment: Remember that in an important sense, an infinite series isn't actually a sum, so you can't necessarily expect it to obey the laws applicable to sums.  An infinite series is defined as a limit of partial sums.  It's reasonable that if you manipulate the addends that result in those partial sums, you'll get different partial sums that result in a different limit.  Indeed, from this perspective, the more surprising result is that there are some conditions (such as absolute convergence) that let you get away with rearranging terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bernhard Riemann proved that a conditionally convergent series may be
> rearranged to converge to any value at all, including ∞ or −∞; see
> Riemann series theorem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_convergence

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem

Comment: Great! Saw this. Very interesting but weird to me. Is there any intuitive explanation to this?

Comment: The intuition is that both the positive and negative parts sum to $\pm \infty$. Then you take positive terms until the sum exceeds a target $L$, then negatives until the partial sum is less, and so on. This works because the general term goes to $0$.

Comment: I am having difficulty in understanding this. Can you please put it in a little more elaborately in your answer? Will be very helpful.

Comment: Read the proof in wikipedia. The first few times through, pay more attention the the words than to the summations.

Answer (score 0):

The plain fact is:  Infinity breaks everything.

We're used to addition being commutative and associative.  But take the series

$$1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + \cdots$$

Associate one way:

$$(1 - 1) + (1 - 1) + \cdots = 0 + 0 + \cdots = 0.$$

Associate another way:

$$1+ (-1+1) + (-1+1) +\cdots = 1+ 0 + 0 +\cdots = 1.$$

So associativity fails to work on infinite sums.  Your example shows that commutativity fails to work on infinite sums.  In Calculus, you learn about "absolute convergence".  And the whole point of absolute convergence is that it restores associativity and commutativity (and many other things) for certain infinite sums.

Comment: For the 2nd one you meant '=1' right?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in an important sense, an infinite series isn't actually a sum, so you can't necessarily expect it to obey the laws applicable to sums. An infinite series is defined as a limit of partial sums. It's reasonable that if you rearrange the terms that result in those partial sums, you'll get different partial sums that result in a different limit. Indeed, from this perspective, the more surprising result is that there are some conditions (such as absolute convergence) that let you get away with rearranging terms.

Comment: I don't quite understand why its more reasonable that you should get different sums. The fact that the terms are infinite doesn't make it obvious to me at least that rearranging would matter. So, for instance even with it being an infinite limit to a partial sum it still means that the terms that were lets say thrown at the end of the series will still get involved in the limit etc. So, to me at least this perspective seems a little windy but that's probably my lack of mathematical prowess.

Comment: Because even though all terms eventually get included in the partial sums, after rearrangement it may *never* be the case that the partial sums have "competing" terms present in the same ratio as in the partial sums of the original series.  In this example, for instance, after rearrangement each partial sum has (at least) twice as many positive terms as negative terms, whereas in the original series the partial sums always contain the same number of positive and negative terms ($\pm 1$) so it's reasonable to expect the partial sums to change.

Comment: Yes. Of course Its reasonable for partial sums to change but the problem arises exactly while taking the limit since (at least in understanding) that by definition means we are including *all the terms* and imbalance of competing terms etc shouldn't matter. So as far as I can see this is very counter-intuitive best fitting (at least till I find a more convincing argument to me) what B Godard says: "breaks everything". Ill be glad if you have more comments to share regarding your reasoning.

Comment: Write out the first 30 or so partial sums of the series in your question to see what the imbalance of competing terms *does* matter.  That imbalance is present in *every single partial sum*, so *of course* it will also be reflected in the limit.  That's really why the Riemann proof works -- you're constructing the sequence of partial sums in such a way as to ensure you end up at your target.